# Get custom Distinct Values from column table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table data and expected data as below

[image]

I wanted to select the distinct ID and Name, irrespective of branch. But I want the branch name to be displayed.
If branch need not be displayed I can use substring. Can the result be achieved using CTE.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What is the "branch"? CS, IS, and EC? Why do expect "Manoj (CS)" in your result and not "Manoij (IS)"? Is there a rule which to pick? Anyway, I suggest you change your database design to three tables: branches, names, branches_names. (Well, you probably find a better name than "names", something like employee, client or the like that says what the name represents.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This result gives a hyperlink to student main profile. He is the same candidate associated to multiple subjects. I have sorted and considered CS. Even Manoj(IS) could be fine. But only one result should come for an id.

Comment: Okay. So you have a student table, which should contain the students' names (Manoj, Ajay, ect.). Then why does the subject table you are showing contain the name again? It should only contain the student ID and the subject/branch ID releating the student record to some subject/branch record. Don't try to fight a bad datamodel with your queries; change the datamodel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't appear to care about which 'branch' needs to be returned, you can simply use a `row_number` within a `CTE` to return just one result per `ID` value:

```
declare @t table(ID int,Name varchar(20));
insert into @t values
 (10,'Manoj (CS)')
,(10,'Manoj (IS)')
,(20,'Ajay (CS)')
,(20,'AJAY (IS)')
,(30,'Sunjay(EC)')
,(40,'Lina(IS)')
,(40,'Lina(CS)')
,(40,'Lina(EC)')
,(50,'Mary(IS)')
,(50,'Mary(EC)');

with d as
(
    select ID
        ,Name
        ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by Name) as rn
    from @t
)
select ID
        ,Name
from d
where rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    Name    |
+----+------------+
| 10 | Manoj (CS) |
| 20 | Ajay (CS)  |
| 30 | Sunjay(EC) |
| 40 | Lina(CS)   |
| 50 | Mary(EC)   |
+----+------------+
```

---

If you do have a preference for the `(CS)` branch however, you would need to alter the `row_number` slightly:

```
with d as
(
    select ID
        ,Name
        ,row_number() over (partition by ID
                            order by case when right(Name,4) = '(CS)'
                                          then 1
                                          else 2
                                          end
                                    ,Name
                            ) as rn
    from @t
)
select ID
        ,Name
from d
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function with `TIES` :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by name);
```

Comment: Very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: Change your datamodel.

If you must live with the table as is, all you want is: all student IDs, each with one branhc/subject name arbitrarily picked. This can be achieved with a simple aggregation:

```
select id, min(name) from mytable group by id;
```